# Id хранится в локалстородже до закрытия вкладки или в течение 24 часов

Tags: javascript, cookie, сессия, localstorage

После авторизации юзера на сайте сохраняю в локалстородж некий id , каждый раз пинку с этим id и проверяю, авторизован ли юзер или нет. (Делаю запрос на сервер)
Можно ли его удалять спустя сутки например или же после того как юзер закрыл вкладку? Если закрыто сохранять в sessionStorage? или лучше использовать куки?

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос. "Можно ли его удалять спустя сутки например или же после того как юзер закрыл вкладку?" Вы разрешения спрашиваете? Что хотите с ним, то и делайте. " Если закрыто сохранять в sessionStorage?" - это вообще, какой-то взаимоисключающий вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Свойство localStorage позволяет получить доступ к локальному Storage объекту. localStorage аналогично свойству sessionStorage. Разница только в том, что свойство sessionStorage хранит данные в течение сеанса (до закрытия браузера), в отличие от данных,  находящихся в свойстве localStorage, которые не имеют ограничений по времени хранения и могут быть удалены только с помощью JavaScript. Ссылка на описание свойства https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

localStorage - после закрытия вкладки удалятся
sessionStorage - после закрытия окна удалятся
coockie - либо вручную чистить либо через JS